# JsonSerializerOptions and ReferenceHandler.Preserve

Tags: .net-core, razor

For the sake of reuse, I have decided to make a razor component to render a list as it seemed to be the right course of action to solve the problem. Note that I am quite new to Core and have been working with the oldschool Web Applications.

Now, I have two entities that create a circular reference,

```
public class Address {
  public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class User {
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to render the component, I do `@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<UsersListComponent>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new { Users = Model.Users }))`

This throws an exception:

```
JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64.
Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.
Path: $.ParameterValues.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Address.Users.Id.
System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_SerializerCycleDetected(int maxDepth)
```

So I began searching yesterday. I have spent the entire evening and this morning, banging my head against a wall I cannot see. I have tried these questions but they did nothing for me.

[WebAPI : JSON ReferenceHandler.Preserve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372706/webapi-json-referencehandler-preserve)

[asp .net core 6 how to update option for json serialization. Date format in Json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72060614/asp-net-core-6-how-to-update-option-for-json-serialization-date-format-in-json)

[.NET 6 - AddJsonOptions with CamelCase not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72034017/net-6-addjsonoptions-with-camelcase-not-working)

A couple of examples of what I have tried:

```
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter>();
                options.OutputFormatters.Add(new SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter(
                    new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web)
                    {
                        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
                        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
                        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                        DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                        DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
                        MaxDepth = 10,
                        WriteIndented = true,
                        NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals
                    }));
            });
```

```
            builder.Services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                options.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                options.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
                options.MaxDepth = 10;
                options.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
                options.WriteIndented = true;
                options.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals;
            });
```

I am getting the feeling that I am barking up the wrong tree because absolutely nothing makes any difference - not even to the worse.

Comment: While this does not answer my question, I got around the problem by using `RenderMode.Static` (thanks to https://andrewlock.net/dont-replace-your-view-components-with-razor-components/). I would still very much like to know what to do with the serializaion problem though!